# Applying BigQuery javascript UDF to groups

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am trying to apply a javascript user defined function to groups. In the following code, --`group by my_group` within `tuple` is commented out. I want to apply the temp function `test` on every `my_group` within `test_data`. The code runs if group by is commented out. If I try to include group by, it produces a "**scalar subquery produced more than one element**". What change should I make so that I can output an array per group (`my_group`)?

```
#standardSQL create function
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION test(a ARRAY<STRING>) 
RETURNS ARRAY< STRING >
LANGUAGE js AS '''
  var combine = function(a) {
    var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
      if (n == 0) {
        if (got.length > 0) {
          all[all.length] = got;
        } return;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
        fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
      } return;
    }
    var all = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
      fn(i, a, [], all);
    }
    all.push(a);
    return all;
  } 
  return combine(a)
''';

 WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT  'Shirt' item, 'Cashless' my_group UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Jeans', 'Cashless' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Jeans', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Cap', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Shirt', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Cap', 'Cashless'

),

tuple as (  
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT item) items
  FROM test_data

  --group by my_group (uncommenting it creates error)
)

select * from unnest(test((select items from tuple)))
```

I am looking for an output like the following:

```
my_group    Item
Cash        Shirt
Cash        Jeans
Cash        Cap
Cash        Shirt,Jeans
Cash        Shirt,Cap
Cash        Jeans,Cap
Cash        Shirt,Jeans,Cap
Cashless    Shirt
Cashless    Jeans
Cashless    Cap
Cashless    Shirt,Jeans
Cashless    Shirt,Cap
Cashless    Jeans,Cap
Cashless    Shirt,Jeans,Cap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below (omitting the function piece to keep answer compact enough ...)

```
 WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT  'Shirt' item, 'Cashless' my_group UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Jeans', 'Cashless' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Jeans', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Cap', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Shirt', 'Cash' UNION ALL
  SELECT  'Cap', 'Cashless'
), tuple as (  
  SELECT my_group, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT item) items
  FROM test_data
  group by my_group 
)
select my_group, item
from tuple,
unnest(test(items)) item
```

with output

[image]